# RegEx for matching unicodes in Informatica

Tags: regex, unicode, regex-group, informatica, informatica-powercenter

Requirement: I need to identify invalid data in address field. For this field valid data is a combination of Numbers, Alphabets, Some special characters(#&-'`./\s), space between two words ( word can be alphabets, number or one of the allowed special character). I am trying to use below reg match expression:

```
'^[a-zA-Z0-9#&\-`./\s]*$'
```

Problem:

1. I am not able to put '(quote character) inside this list .
2. it also allows space at the end of data which it should not.

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Why are you not allowed to put the quote inside the character class? Do you get an error or do you use the same delimiters? Perhaps escape it? The space at the end is because `\s` is also accepted. You might repeat that expression without the `\s` and start the repeating pattern with a space `^[a-zA-Z0-9#&\-`./]+(?: [a-zA-Z0-9#&\-`./]+)*$` See https://regex101.com/r/sVI7sV/1

Comment: ' doesn't work with escape character too in Informatica. It work in SQL query and other places but in informatica it doesn't, so I am not looking for an alternate in Informatica. and yes, it fails if I put ' in this list ( both cases with escape character and without escape character)

Comment: Have you tried putting [^ ]$ at the end of the regexp i.e after star i.e. to not allow spaces at the end

Answer (score 3):

I'm not familiar with Informatica, however you might be able to replace ' with `\x27`, " with \x22, ‘ with \x{2018} and ‘ with \x{2019} and it may work.

---

[This expression](https://regex101.com/r/hp9kgA/1) shows how that would work:

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9#&\-`\.\/\s\x22\x27\x{2019}\x{2018}]+)$
```

[image]

This graph shows how the expression functions:

[image]

#### Description

The correct use of \x2019 and \x2018 would be \x{2018} and \x{2019}. Apparently, without that, the engine would consider that as a **\x20 and 18** or **\x20 and 19**, which [I did not know that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56029527/matching-unicode-characters-by-number-using-pcre).

[image]

Comment: Your pattern still accepts a space at the end. See https://regex101.com/r/iFx4Jv/1

Comment: Thanks. this works in some cases. I see my data also includes ’ which is different than ' OR ` ( I do not even see ’ in keyboard). can someone help me how to use ’ in reg exp ( I tried putting it in the same exp both directly  and with \’ but it does not work in informatica ).

Comment: In Informatica I can not put single quote directly in the square bracket(It fails, even though it works in normal regular exp), even with escape character it does not work but \x27 worked for '. Do I need to use something else for ’, because  \x27 is not matching pattern with ’ ?

Comment: Thanks Emma. It seems this doesn't work. I was checking at the link you provided above:   Data: Anything that you wish including 12 ‘                                                                              Expression I am using: ^[a-zA-Z0-9#&\-`\x27\x2019\x2018\x22.\s]*$

Comment: Hi Emma, can you please take a look at above and confirm if you still think \x2019 is correct?

Comment: Hi Emma, no it does not recognize ‘ using  \x2019 and  \x2018 . In my above example pattern match fails.

Comment: Correct, that does not work in Informatica. and using \x2019 and \x2018 to recognize ‘ does not work in https://regex101.com/r/IX71ve/1 either.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to validate address, then informatica offers Address verification service and it works pretty good for most of the countries .
If you really want to validate the address only with regex , then what emma has given should be ample and then remove the spaces at the end with ltrim-rtrim combo as below,

```
ltrim(rtim(re_ex_result_here))
```

This will help you to eliminate the spaces at the end.

[More on Informatica Address validator here](https://www.informatica.com/products/data-quality/data-as-a-service/address-verification.html#fbid=YT6JSwKbET5)